# How to use multiple commands to generate saluation, title(if it is not empty) and name

Tags: spacing

I try to generate the name with title (if there is one), prename and name. But there is no space after the salutation.

[image]

If there is no title `\def\cvTitel{}` everything is fine:
[image]

My code looks like:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{xifthen}


\def\cvSetName{nachname}

\newcommand{\cvAnrede}{Herr}
\newcommand{\cvTitel}{}
\newcommand{\cvVorname}{Max}
\newcommand{\cvNachname}{Mustermann}

\newcommand{\cvSetTitel}[1]{\ifthenelse{\isempty{#1}}{}{#1}%
}

\newcommand{\setName}[1]{%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{nachname}}{\cvAnrede \cvSetTitel{\cvTitel} \cvNachname }{\cvVorname }%
}

\newcommand{\setCompleteName}[1]{%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{nachname}}{\cvSetTitel{\cvTitel} \cvVorname \cvNachname }{\cvVorname }%
}

\newcommand{\cvName}{\setName{\cvSetName} }
\newcommand{\cvFullName}{\setCompleteName{\cvSetName}}


\begin{document}
\raggedright
Bereits während seines Studiums hat \cvName vielseitige Erfahrungen in der Softwareindustrie gesammelt. 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This way?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{xifthen}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\def\cvSetName{nachname}

\newcommand{\cvAnrede}{Herr}
\newcommand{\cvTitel}{}
\newcommand{\cvVorname}{Max}
\newcommand{\cvNachname}{Mustermann}

\newcommand{\cvSetTitel}[1]{\ifdefempty{#1}{}{#1\ }%
}

\newcommand{\setName}[1]{%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{nachname}}{\cvAnrede\ \cvSetTitel{\cvTitel}\cvNachname\ }{\cvVorname\ }%
}

\newcommand{\setCompleteName}[1]{%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{nachname}}{\cvSetTitel{\cvTitel}\cvVorname\ \cvNachname\ }{\cvVorname\ }%
}

\newcommand{\cvName}{\setName{\cvSetName}}
\newcommand{\cvFullName}{\setCompleteName{\cvSetName}}


\begin{document}
\raggedright
\section{Without title}

Bereits während seines Studiums hat \cvName vielseitige Erfahrungen in der Softwareindustrie gesammelt. 

Full name: \cvFullName something after 

\section{With title}
\renewcommand{\cvAnrede}{Herr}
\renewcommand{\cvTitel}{Dr}
\renewcommand{\cvVorname}{Max}
\renewcommand{\cvNachname}{Mustermann}

Bereits während seines Studiums hat \cvName vielseitige Erfahrungen in der Softwareindustrie gesammelt. 

Full name: \cvFullName something after 
\end{document}
```

[image]